# Is there a way to automatically input text in the different text box using Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests

I wanted to test a registration form with a lot of text boxes.
 Instead of manually using the **.sendkeys()** to each text box, is there a way to automatically input texts into each and every textbox in the page?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code trials. A good question will include a [repro]. As it exists, your question does not have enough information for us to provide a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you'd like to have as little lines of code as possible for a form of text boxes with each their individual xpaths?

A way to do this you could use a list of xpaths (and text), which you iterate through and fill in automatically.

Note, you'd probably want to add a WebdriverWait to wait for the element to be loaded on the screen but this snippet might help you on your way.

```
# list of tuples consisting of a xpath and text to fill in that textbox
my_list = [('//*[@id="textbox_email"]', 'example@email.com'), ('//*[@id="textbox_password"]', 'pwd123'), (..., ...)]

for xpath, text in my_list:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).send_keys(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use page factory to store the locators and use from there every time or you can try the Data/Text driven framework also.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).